PhpStorm a keyboard shortcut for on hover hint
When PhpStorm shows You a warning about a variable, method, class, or whatever, and then you hover the cursor over it after a ~second a hint pops up.
What is the keyboard shortcut to show this helpful message without touching a filthy mouse?
Or how to set it?


During creation of this question I tried ctrl+shift+a, and typed "hover". The first result was "On mouse hover", press enter to enter the settings.
On your left side, You will see Keymap tab, go there, and on Your bottom-right side You'll see Other -> Hover info. Double click on it and set the desired shortcut.

